# Namespacing class using a single element in LESS

Tags: css, less

The title is worded poorly, I think an example will better show what I'm trying to do.

I have a LESS file which is actually a CSS file that I grabbed from another site. I want to use these classes, but only when another class is also attached to the element.

An example of what I want to do, using valid LESS:

```
.external-style {
  &.foo {
    color: red;
  }
  &.bar{
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

But because there's probably over ten thousand rules I don't want to apply this to each rule individually.

What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
.external-style {
  & {
    .foo {
      color: red;
    }
    .bar {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible in LESS?

The advantage for me is that I can then do this:

```
<div class="external-style foo"></div>
```

instead of this:

```
<div class="external-style"><div class="foo"></div></div>
```

Which is important when I'm using the `display` property.

Comment: Short of doing something like `.external-style { &.foo, .foo { some: rule; } }`, I don't believe what you're asking for is possible.

Comment: @JoshBurgess Not sure what you wrote accomplishes what I want anyhow - I don't need the style to be available within an element with `.external-style`, it only needs to be available when `external-style` is applied to the same element.

Comment: Then what exactly does using the default syntax not give you?  You could have one class `foo` and then another as `.external-style { .foo { }}` and as long as a containing element had `.external-style`, that would only be applied in that scenario.

Comment: not possible, see https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/2465

Comment: @JoshBurgess "as long as a containing element" - that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. As far as I'm concerned, if I have to accomplish this by using more HTML then it's a missing feature.

Comment: @Iwansbrough.  Went back and re-read your comment, missed the point originally.  Find and replace is probably the tool that you'll want to use here, rather than reworking LESS.  Namespacing like you're discussing doesn't exist in the language.